# Unable to tokenise data in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, twint

This is my code, I want to import a CSV file and only tokenize texts from one column. the column is named 'tweet'. I'm unable to get the output for this code

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
import numpy

from nltk import sent_tokenize
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import pos_tag


data = pd.read_csv('/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/dingdang/finaldid.csv')

Texts = list(data['tweet'].values)

tokenData = [nltk.word_tokenize(tweet) for tweet in Texts]
```

Answer (score 0):

The NLTK data package includes a pre-trained Punkt tokenizer for English.
Use this

> nltk.download('punkt')

Comment: doesn't answer my question

Comment: I tried the code and it worked fine. Can you specify the problem you are facing or what error you are getting?